# How to convert price column to integer from character (in R)

Tags: r, integer, character

I tried using as.integer() and as.numeric() but NAs were added in. [image]

Comment: See `parse_number()`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(price = parse_number(price))

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  item       price calories
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>
1 banana      1         105
2 apple       0.75       95
3 peach       3          55
4 peach       4          55
5 clementine  2.5        35
```

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: Did you change df to fruits?